# Eclipse launch configuration is missing when exporting a Spring boot project to a runnable jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot project `httpCommonInterface`, and have run it in the Eclipse IDE, so I have a  launch configuration for it, both in the ide, and on the `<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches` folder.(Also I noticed that there is a mismatch between them.)

[image]
[image]

---

The problem is when I tried to export it to a runnable jar, I can't find that configuration. 
(They are different for all these three lists!)

---

[image]

Without the configuration I can't export that project. How can I fix this?

Comment: What type of launch configuration is it (which section does it appear in in the Run > Run Configurations... dialog)? Only Java Applications are shown in the Runnable Jar dialog, there are many other types.

Comment: @greg-449 thanks for your advice. I have figured out the cause. As you said, Only Java Applications are shown in the Runnable Jar dialog. So I firstly run the Spring boot project as a `java application`, then its lunch configuration is listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only **Java Applications launch configurations** are shown in the Runnable Jar dialog.

Even if the Spring boot project has been run as a `Spring boot application` (and a configration file is created, and we can see the spring boot lunch configuration in the ide), we still cannot export it to a runnable jar file.

So the solution is that we firstly **run the Spring boot project as a java application**, then its launch configuration is listed.

---

How to run the Spring boo project as a java application:

1. right click on the project;
2. `run as`-> `run configration`;
3. on the left part of the window, choose one instance of `Java Application`(if none, `new` one);

   4. config the `run configration`, like the `Project` and `Main Class` in the `Project` tab.

Comment: FYI 'launch' not 'lunch'. Lunch is like dinner.